# IIS7 and Crystal Reports 11 Frequent App Pool Recycling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, crystal-reports

I am running and embedded Crystal Reports 11 App on IIS.  I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and IIS7.

I have a button that the user clicks and it generates about 40 .pdf files using the Crystal Reports engine.

When the user clicks the button, Crystal creates each .pdf and stores it to disk (disk on the server).  Periodically this process hangs and the reports do not get created.

I figured out that when I go shut down the server and recycle the app pool a few times, this fixes the problem.  But this seems to be happening frequently (about every 2 or 3 iterations of the run of the 40 reports)

Is there any reasoning to this happening?  I know that there are ways to set the automatic recycling, but how can I determine what is a good value for me?  I feel like I could recycle every hour.  Seems like too frequent.  Is there something about CR (and my heavy use of it) that may be causing me to use more memory than a web app that is not using CR?

Comment: Crystal Reports isn't giving any errors when generating?

Comment: No, nothing in server error logs either

Comment: Go in, recycle app pool, and then it works.  Sometimes you need to recycle several times.

Comment: maybe it's a time-out problem, do they take a long time to load?

Comment: just a few minutes for all of the reports